# Free the memory where a uintptr_t is pointing to

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I have the following problem:

First of all I have struct:

```
struct Filehandler
{
    const int id = 1;
};
```

Then I have two methods - one for creating a new Filehandler struct and one for deleting the struct. Because the whole code is part of a Webassembly Plugin for a Rust project, I have to use pointers.

So this is my method for allocating the struct:

```
uintptr_t newhandler() {

    struct Filehandler* filehandler = (struct Filehandler*) malloc(sizeof(struct Filehandler));
    uintptr_t *ptr = (uintptr_t *)&filehandler;
    uintptr_t temp = (uintptr_t)ptr;
    return temp;
}
```

I know this somehow looks confusing but I have to retrieve the address the pointer is pointing as value. Thats why im returning my pointer as value.

Now I want to create a function which deletes the struct. As parameter the function gets an `uintptr_t`:

```
void destroy_handler(uintptr_t ptr) {
    ........?
}
```

So my question is: Is it possible to delete the Struct `filehandler`, if I have a the pointer to it stored in a `uintptr_t` and give it as a value to the `destroy_handler` function. And if this is possible how do I do it?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `const int id = 1;` isn't valid C because you can't initialize members of a struct like that. In general, avoid `const` qualifiers of members but make an instance of the whole struct `const` instead.
- `uintptr_t newhandler()` should be `uintptr_t newhandler(void)`, the former is obsolete style and should not be used.
- Casting the result of malloc is pointless. Consider `struct Filehandler* filehandler = malloc (sizeof *filehandler);` instead.
- `uintptr_t *ptr = (uintptr_t *)&filehandler;` doesn't make any sense, you are casting the malloc:ed *pointer's address* which is a local variable. Drop the `&`.
- `uintptr_t temp = (uintptr_t)ptr;` doesn't make any sense because you are casting the address of a local pointer again.

---

Fixed code should look something like:

```
struct Filehandler
{
    int id;
};

const struct Filehandler FH = {.id = 1};

...

#include <stdlib.h>

uintptr_t newhandler (void) 
{
  struct Filehandler* filehandler = malloc(sizeof *filehandler);
  if(filehandler == NULL)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  // optional line: memcpy(filehandler, &FH, sizeof FH);

  return (uintptr_t)filehandler;
}


void destroy_handler(uintptr_t ptr) 
{
  free((void*)ptr);
}
```